# get error when upload image in pathinfo() with code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

i have method for uploading image, but i get multiple error messages if i run this method with error:

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: pathinfo() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
>
> Filename: core/Loader.php
>
> Line Number: 759
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Array to string conversion
>
> Filename: core/Loader.php
>
> Line Number: 760
>
> An Error Was Encountered
>
> Unable to load the requested file: Array.php

how do I fix the code so as not to get an error ? where is the problem ?
thanks

```
function upload_image()
         {
            $config = array(
                            'file_name'=> 'hallo.jpg',
                            'upload_path'=>'./application/views/photo',
                            'allowed_types'=>'gif|jpg|png',
                            'max_size'=>'1024',
                            'max_width'=>'1600',
                            'max_height'=>'1200'
                            );

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if($this->upload->do_upload())
            {
                $data['breadcrumb1'] = "Member";
                $data['breadcrumb'] = "Add Member";
                $data['content']='admin-cms/member/add';
                $this->load->view('admin-cms/index', $data);
            }else
            {
                $data['content']= array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors('<span class="error">','</span>'));
                $this->load->view('admin-cms/index', $data);
            }

         }
```

Comment: Can You mark 759 and 760 lines?

Comment: $_ci_ext = pathinfo($_ci_view, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$_ci_file = ($_ci_ext == '') ? $_ci_view.'.php' : $_ci_view;

Comment: @GeorgeSazanovich do i have delete it?